# Asus laptop backlight keys not working

Tags: nvidia, keyboard, shortcut-keys, brightness, asus

I have an asus F554L laptop and the fn + f5, f6 brightness control keys are not working. I can control the brightness through settings. I have tried adding `pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi=` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, but the only thing it does is to stop me from controlling brightness from settings.

I have tried to run `acpi_listen` and `xev`, but they do not generate any output when I press the keys, although the other fn keys do show output and work correctly.

I have not tried to modify/create `20-intel.conf` because I have a nvidia graphics card.

`ls /sys/class/backlight` shows:

```
asus-nb-wmi  intel_backlight
```

and `cat /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness`

```
100 
562
```

I am using ubuntu 16.10.

Thanks for the help.